# Convert audio doubles to bytes

Tags: vb.net, audio, type-conversion

I am dealing with raw PCM audio data (the audio data of a PCM file without the header).

This data is provided to me in the form of a vector of double.

I would like to pass this data to another function, and this function expects the audio data in the form of a byte vector.

I tried

```
    Dim nBytes() As Byte = nDoubles.SelectMany(Function(d) BitConverter.GetBytes(d)).ToArray()
```

but that wouldn't give the expected results.

I guess I have to deal with the conversion manually, but I am unsure how this should be done.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Comment: What you need to do depends on the format (specifically, the 'bit-age') of the data in the doubles, and the format that the other function expects.  So, what's the format of your raw PCM source data? 8-bit? 16-bit? 24-bit?

Comment: @Ian It is 16 bit, 48kHz, mono.

Comment: And what format is required by the other function?

Comment: @Ian The other function expects bytes are if they were read directly from a WAV file.

Comment: But of what format?  Either you'll need to specify the input format to it, or it will expect a certain one.

Comment: @Ian What exactely do you mean? It is a Wav PCM audio. Is that what you mean?

Comment: What is the sampe rate and bits per sample that it expects?

Comment: @Ian Samplerate: 48000 Hz, bits per sample: 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the required format for the other function is 16-bit, 48 kHz, which is the same as your source data, it's a simple case of converting the source to an array of Short, then serializing this as a Byte array.

The problem with the code you suggest for this is that the first step is missed, so it basically serializes the Double array.  However, you can re-use this for the second step.  So, you can do something like:

```
    Dim nShorts() As Short = New Short(nDoubles.Length - 1) {}

    For i = 0 To nDoubles.Length - 1
        nShorts(i) = Convert.ToInt16(nDoubles(i))
    Next

    Dim nBytes() As Byte = nShorts.SelectMany(Function(s) BitConverter.GetBytes(s)).ToArray()
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to multiply nDoubles(i) with 32768, but apart from that it works great, thank you!